# Change outbound IP - centos

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, routing, ip-address

i have a server (linux/centos) and my default ip is:
111.111.111.111   so i bought another ip (ip failover) 222.222.222.222

*if i visit in browser 111.111.111.111 or 222.222.222.222 its opening same page*

so i have **eth0:**

```
UUID="2f99a6-6566-sb24-bd0e-bf5a8d4a1765"
IPADDR="111.111.111.111"
GATEWAY="111.111.111.1"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

also i created **eth0:0**

same as above just changed

```
DEVICE="eth0:0"
IPADDR="222.222.222.222"
#GATEWAY="111.111.111.1"(commented it)
```

when i run
**curl --interface eth0 ifconfig.co**    the response is 111.111.111.111

**curl --interface eth0:0 ifconfig.co**    the response is 222.222.222.222

but when i use wget or **ffmpeg**(i just want to find solution for ffmpeg )
then ip is 111.111.111.111

so how i can make **default** outbound IP to be *222.222.222.222* (its my second ip/ i bought as failover ip)

Comment: Do not obfuscate so badly using `111.111.111.111` and `222.222.222.222`. Please read instead RFC5737

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact requirements, but the methods you can use are:

- Standard Routing Tables (Destination Based)
- Policy based routing (allows various routing criterias)
- Network Namespaces

I think in your use case Network Namespaces in combination with aliases could be an effective choice.
For details on that solution path, consider:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface

Comment: can u send me any example what i need to do